# Assignment to ColumnDefinitions with binding to xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, type-conversion, grid

I need the column to be dynamic and the values ​​to change when I click the button.

I made a method that, when activated, will pass the value to a variable that will be used for association through binding.

```
private void clickedColumnDefinition()
        {
           ColumnDefinition1 = 420;
        }
```

The property this method have a declared GrindLenght:

```
private GridLength _columnDefinition1;
    public GridLength ColumnDefinition1 {
        get { return _columnDefinition1; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _columnDefinition1, value); }
    }
```

In xaml define the column like this:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ColumnDefinition1, Converter={StaticResource numberToGridLengthConverter}}"/>
```

The converter I'm using is this one, but nothing happens when I press the button.

```
public class NumberToGridLengthConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var numberValue = (double)value;
            return new GridLength(numberValue, GridUnitType.Star);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var gridLength = (GridLength)value;
            return gridLength.Value;
        }
    }
```

what can be wrong?

Comment: please do NOT post code, xaml or errors as images

Comment: Sorry, first time I create a topic, I already fixed it

Comment: `ColumnDefinition1` is a `field`, not a `property`.  You can only bind to C# public properties

Comment: I went wrong, updated the property

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the `RowDefinition`'s Height to a Dynamic value. You can do as follows:

1.created a view model `RowHeightClass`

```
public class RowHeightClass: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        bool swith;

        //public GridLength rowFirstHeight { set; get; }
        GridLength _rowFirstHeight;
        public GridLength RowFirstHeight
        {
            get => _rowFirstHeight;
            set => SetProperty(ref _rowFirstHeight, value);
        }


        //public GridLength rowSecondHeight { set; get; }
        GridLength _rowSecondHeight;
        public GridLength RowSecondHeight
        {
            get => _rowSecondHeight;
            set => SetProperty(ref _rowSecondHeight, value);
        }

        public RowHeightClass()
        {
            //initial RowFirstHeight and  RowSecondHeight
            RowFirstHeight = new GridLength(15);

            RowSecondHeight = new GridLength(15);
        }


        public ICommand ResetHeightCommand => new Command(resetHeight);

        private void resetHeight()
        { //reset RowFirstHeight and  RowSecondHeight
            if (!swith)
            {
                RowFirstHeight = new GridLength(50);
                RowSecondHeight = new GridLength(50);
            }
            else {
                RowFirstHeight = new GridLength(15);
                RowSecondHeight = new GridLength(15);
            }

            swith = !swith;
        }


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

2.bind the properties in `MainPage.xaml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DynamicHeightApp.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Orange">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding RowFirstHeight}" />
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding RowSecondHeight}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Testing Color Change on this one" TextColor="Red"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Testing Height" />
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="Testing Height Change on this one through binding"/>
        </Grid>

        <Button  Text="reset" Command="{Binding ResetHeightCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

3.MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
    RowHeightClass rowHeightClass;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

         rowHeightClass = new RowHeightClass();

        BindingContext = rowHeightClass;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

I added two properties `RowFirstHeight` and `RowSecondHeight` and implemented interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`  for this view model, if we change the value of above properties, the UI will update automatically.